# How to extract the number of "likes" from a Facebook page using R

Tags: facebook, r, facebook-graph-api

I want to extract the number of users who have "liked " a page, using the R language with the Facebook Graph API. I am new to Facebook Graph API.

I dont think there is a package in R related to this API.

Is there any tutorial on how to access the Facebook API graph objects using R?

Comment: Take a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5573862/accessing-facebook-api-from-r-for-text-mining

Comment: I want to access using Facebook Graph Api.

Comment: Related work and tutorials on accessing the Facebook Graph API using R: http://www.brocktibert.com/blog/2012/01/19/358/ and http://romainfrancois.blog.free.fr/index.php?post/2012/01/15/Crawling-facebook-with-R and http://applyr.blogspot.com/2012/01/mining-facebook-data-most-liked-status.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

jan: I am not at all aware of R language. But actually you can easily fetch number of likes of your page using graph api with the following url:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/${page_id} - (Can see the response by hitting this url on a browser)
```

Just place this code in the javascript section of your page

```
FB.api( '/${page_id}', function (response) { alert(response.likes) } );
```